# Exception during a WebClient request for a FTP download

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

I'm trying to develop a function that downloads a file in a FTP directory. I try this way

```
static void descargarFic(string ficFTP, string user, string pass, string dirLocal)
{
    Library.WriteErrorLog(ficFTP + " -> " + dirLocal);
    try
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
        client.DownloadFile(ficFTP, dirLocal);
        Library.WriteErrorLog("Done");
        client.Dispose();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Library.WriteErrorLog(e.Message);
    }
}
```

The WriteErrorLog write on a file the string passed. So, I'm calling that function in this way:

`descargarFic("ftp://something-here/incoming/file.xml.gz", "anonymous", "password", @"C:\folder1\file.xml.gz");`

But I receive the exception `Exception during a WebClient request for a FTP download` when I try to download it.

I'm pretty sure that it's some kind of problem with the URI, but I didn't realize where it is.

EDIT: Using `Library.WriteErrorLog(e.InnerException);`

The exception given is

> The given access path's format is not supported.

Comment: As a comment, I don't know how's that exception in english, jus translated it from spanish.